# Convert server.createobject from classic ASP to ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, vbscript, asp-classic

Hi i have a function that was created in ASP classic and want to convert the function in ASP.NET Vb . Below is code that was using in Classic ASP

```
Function chargeIt(CARD_NUM, EX_MONTH, EX_YEAR, AMOUNT, COMMENT)    
url = "https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll"
set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP") 
xmlhttp.open "POST", url, false 
xmlhttp.send "x_description=""Violation Payment For "&COMMENT&"""&x_Version=3.1&x_Delim_Data=True&x_Login=xnxx&x_Tran_Key= 9&x_Amount="&amount&"&x_Card_Num="&card_num&"&x_Exp_Date="&ex_month&ex_year&"&x_Type=AUTH_CAPTURE"
    Dim arrContents(150,0)

    contents=split(xmlhttp.responseText,",")
    'response.write(xmlhttp.responseText)
    i=0
    for each value in contents
    arrContents(i,0)=value
    i=i+1
    next
    SELECT CASE arrContents(0,0)
    CASE "1"
        status="Approved"
    END SELECT

    chargeIt=status
end function
```

Comment: This looks like a payment gateway.  Have you had a look to see if they provide ASP.net API code?  If their examples are in C# then there are free conversion tools available.  C# to VB usually works better than the other way, mainly because VB isn't case sensitive

Comment: We can help you with your code but we aren't going to just rewrite it. Authorize.net has sample code in vb.net here: http://developer.authorize.net/downloads/samplecode/

Comment: Doesn't ASP.NET have it's own class for sending HTTP Requests? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You may use the System.Net.WebRequest class instead. It is part of the .NET Framework.

For example:

```
Dim strURL
Dim objXML As WebRequest
Dim strResponse As WebResponse

objXML = WebRequest.Create(strURL)
strResponse = objXML.GetResponse()

objXML = Nothing
strResponse.Close()
```

Google on WebRequest VB.NET and you should be able to get going...